# Mysql summing zeros verses selecting non zeros

Tags: mysql

If I have a table column that has either 0 or 1 in each row,
which of the following is the best option:

```
SELECT SUM(myCol) as v FROM mytable
SELECT SUM(mycol) as v FROM mytable WHERE mycol=1
SELECT COUNT(mycol) as v FROM mytable WHERE mycol=1
```

UPDATE:
Just one moment before the 5th kind person will vote to close my Q:

I don't know the cardinality yet, nor indices either it was just asked as a theoretical Q.
Actually I was hoping that maybe one of statements is always better then the others.
consider for example 3rd and 2nd - I hoped that maybe some one would come and say that `COUNT` option is better because (maybe - this is speculations not facts) the rows are already being counted when performing the `WHERE` anyway...
or comparing the first two options someone might say (again - my speculations) that as long as there is no index on mycol then the first would always be better because it needs less comparisons - or the other way around the second is better because it needs less adding actions (which are possibly more expensive then the comparisons).

maybe the question should have been stated more along the lines of "Under what conditions can one be sure of the superiority of one of those statments over one of the other two (or both)".

sorry if I gave someone the impression that I was to lazy to do an EXPLAIN...

Comment: **`SELECT COUNT(mycol) as v FROM mytable WHERE mycol=1`**

Comment: I would say `SELECT SUM(myCol) as v FROM mytable`

Comment: What cardinality do you have? Any indices? If you have just 2% rows with `1` and an index on `mycol`, choose option 2 or 3.

Comment: all good comments, please see my UPDATE in the Q.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, `SELECT SUM(myCol) as v FROM mytable` would be best...

### WHY?

For `SELECT SUM(mycol) as v FROM mytable WHERE mycol=1` it will have execution as below.

```
 SELECT mycol as v FROM mytable
 FROM ABOVE SUM data
 FROM ABOVE CHECK WHERE mycol=1
```

For `SELECT COUNT(mycol) as v FROM mytable WHERE mycol=1` same as above...

```
 SELECT mycol as v FROM mytable
 FROM ABOVE COUNT data
 FROM ABOVE CHECK WHERE mycol=1
```

However, for `SELECT SUM(myCol) as v FROM mytable` it would be

```
 SELECT mycol as v FROM mytable
 FROM ABOVE SUM data
```

I hope this answers...

---

Or best, just write `EXPLAIN` before each query and see performance...

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SUM(myCol) as v FROM mytable
EXPLAIN SELECT SUM(mycol) as v FROM mytable WHERE mycol=1
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(mycol) as v FROM mytable WHERE mycol=1
```

Comment: If there is an index on `mycol`, `WHERE mycol=1` will limit the amount of records read, unlike other options.

Comment: @Fahim I doubt if your breakdown to steps actually describes what realy happens. e.g. how can you first sum and only then apply the WHERE to the results ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your requirements.
Though if you want to add up the number of columns for 1 value then I will prefer

`SELECT COUNT(mycol) as v FROM mytable WHERE mycol=1`

Comment: This was also my gut instinct, but It would be nice if you could explain why you thing so.